# nopCommerce not running modified controller method

Tags: caching, nopcommerce

I am currently making a webshop based on nopCommerce, but I need unique products per customer. 
To achieve this, I edited the catalogController to filter the products according to my own database tables.

The code I used for this works perfectly when running nopCommerce from Visual Studio 2013: the correct products are displayed for each customer and no products are displayed when nobody is logged in.

I deploy nopCommerce to my local machine and then copy over the files to our (IIS7) webserver, after which it also works exactly as expected (without restarting the server).

The problem starts after restarting the webserver. If the webserver gets restarted, every customer will always see every product.

For debugging purposes, I made an ActionFilterAttribute to see if the function still gets called (it does get called) and I added a log message to the first line of the edited function to check if the function runs and it turns out that the function does not run.

I suspect that nopCommerce caches the category page on starting the application. I know nopCommerce uses caching but I cannot find any info about what is cached or how to disable it (either part of it or completely turn off caching all together)

Comment: if you not want to load your category and product from cache so find cache in category method and product method in catalog and product controller and remove caching then you get every time fresh filter content in every request.

Comment: @Vap As I explained in the post: The method never runs. I have a line that writes to a log file at the top of the method and the log file doesn't get written to. Any edits to the method do not affect anything.

Comment: Without looking at your code, it's hard for us to comment much. :)

Comment: @wooncherk there is little code that is relevant to the problem. I could show the code I use to make the log entries and show the ActionFilterAttribute I made but any other code is irrelevant as it's never reached although it should be.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to disable all caching for testing purposes. I just changed the following two rows in DependencyRegistrar.cs (Nop.Web.Framework):

```
builder.RegisterType<MemoryCacheManager>().As<ICacheManager>().Named<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_static").SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<PerRequestCacheManager>().As<ICacheManager>().Named<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_per_request").InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

to

```
builder.RegisterType<NopNullCache>().As<ICacheManager>().Named<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_static").SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<NopNullCache>().As<ICacheManager>().Named<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_per_request").InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

This changes the cache-managers to a "non-caching" manager.

(I'm totally new at NopCommerce so there might something that I have missed, but this works for me.)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into issues at some time with IIS not running the updated code. You must make sure that proper DLL's (updated ones) are loaded at any time. In your case, the file is most probably Nop.Web.dll

Check if:

1. **You might have a DLL in a referenced path that loads and overrides the updated code.** 
   I had problems with a plugin not being updated until I found out that somehow the plugin's DLL got into the "bin" folder on the server and over-rid the actual plugin DLL in the Plugins folder.
2. **IIS might not load and cache your updated DLL properly.**
   On a dev machine, I once discovered that DLL's inside the `Temporary ASP.NET files` were not up to date. Shutting down IIS and emptying the folder helps but my problem was always recurring until I did a full Windows reinstall, unfortunately.

   The folder path for .NET 4+ is `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`